# App or Service to Automatically Backup Photos in iCloud Photo Library?

Tags: icloud, backup, photos

This is my situation:

- MacBook and iPhone both using Photos.app and both using iCloud Photo Library
- Neither device has enough local storage to keep the originals, so they're both set to the *Optimize Storage* option
- I'd like an automated backup solution for the photo collection in iCloud Photo Library...

I've read [How do I backup photos *from* iCloud Photo Library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199554/how-do-i-backup-photos-from-icloud-photo-library) - along with other Q&As and pages, so I'm aware I could do things like:

- Change the location of the library on the Mac, to an external drive, and switch the setting to *Download Originals...
- Use iCloud.com to download photos, on any machine with a big hard disk or the current Mac, to an external drive...

What I'd prefer is an automated backup process. I know that iCloud Photo Library is fairly new; does anyone know of a Mac app, or an online service, that uses a user's iCloud credentials to take regular backups?

Comment: Yep, photos on iCloud... As it stands the iCloud storage is the only complete copy of the photo library... I can manually execute a backup, but an automated process is the way to go... To another cloud? Yeah, possibly. Eg to a backblaze account, or similar. Or... Perhaps it could be done on a local machine, backing up to any storage that machine can see...